# Hide Div On Page load depending upon checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to hide a div on page load, its depend upon checkbox, if checkbox is checked then it is hide on page load if not then show the div what to do Plz help....

```
try{
st1=con.createStatement();
String QueryString = "SELECT c.course_code,c.course_id,t.topic_name,l.lo_name,l.session,l.status,l.lo_id FROM course as c JOIN topic as t JOIN los as l WHERE c.course_id=t.course_id AND t.topic_id=l.topic_id AND t.topic_id = '"+top1+"'";

rs1 = st1.executeQuery(QueryString);
while (rs1.next()){
    id=rs1.getInt(7);
    course=rs1.getString(1);
    topicName=rs1.getString(3);
   lo=rs1.getString(4);
   sess=rs1.getString(5);


enter code here
```

}
}catch(){

}

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? This question does not provide enough information. Could you please add more detail and/or your code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/aqakap/1/edit

In html:

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox" checked/><label for="check">Check</label>
<div id="msg">
  aloha
</div>
```

In javascript:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("check"),
    msg = document.getElementById('msg');

if (checkbox.checked)
  msg.style.display = "none";
else
  msg.style.display = "block";
```

mz

Comment: No Actually Problem is, This check box is inside While loop so i am not able to its unique id,if loop goes for 5 times then how i will identify the particular checkbox name or id

Comment: 1. You did not write anything about loop and not unique ID's in original question. Please clarify this at the beggining.
2. What do you mean by "while" loop? On server side? Or you're looping through them on client side?

Comment: Actually values are coming from database in the divs and checkbox is also there ,i have to hide the div if corresponding checkbox is checked

Comment: Sorry, I think I can't help you. There's no clear picture about what you want achieve. You've shown some (probably) Java code, but you did not tell if you're using any frameworks. It seems you want to hide it on server side but then "javascript" tag is not relevant at all.

Answer (score 0):

Super vague answer to super vague question:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var checked = document.getElementById('checkbox').checked;
    document.getElementById('div').style.display = checked ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Give any classname to that div.
Jquery Code for page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".classname").hide();
});
```

If check box is checked then, in that select box, put

> onclick='show_selected_div();'

JS Code

```
function show_selected_div(){
  $(".classname").show();
}
```

Comment: Div is also inside while loop

Comment: -1 as jQuery is not mentioned in the question. I would clarify the technology by commenting on the question first.

Comment: Buddy, its really nice that your referring your technology but you forgot to mention that do not use Jquery. Jquery make the things easier and good. So I suggest Jquery code. Anyway its your choice, how to react.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are using jQuery, this should be what you need.

```
$('<checkboxid>').click ( function() {
  $('<divid>').hide();
});
```

Comment: -1 as jQuery is not mentioned in the question. I would clarify the technology by commenting on the question first.